# Positioned images - sending positioned images from a doc to a google form using apps script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, position, google-docs, google-forms

I'm trying to send multiple positioned images anchored to a paragraph to a google form. However, for example, if there are 3 positioned images anchored to the paragraph it will send 3 images of the last anchored image. Furthermore, if there are 2, it will send 2 images of the last anchored image and if there is only 1, it will send just one image of the last anchored image which happens to be the only one and the first.

Here is the code:

```
else if (questType == 'IMAGE'){

 var childIndex = questions[i][2]; //this value was stored in the questions array that is a parameter of the main function
 var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
 var docBody = doc.getBody();
 var child = docBody.getChild(childIndex).asParagraph();
if (child.getPositionedImages().length > 0){
   var posImgs = child.getPositionedImages();
   var noImgs = posImgs.length;
   
   DocumentApp.getUi().alert(posImgs);   //test for correct no of images
    for (var j = 0; j<noImgs; j++){
     var img = posImgs[j];                            
     var imgBlob = img.getBlob();
     item = form.addImageItem();
     item.setImage(imgBlob);
   }
  } 
 }
```

This code is part of an outer/main loop where item has already been declared at the beginning of the loop. Can anyone enlighten me with this?

Thanks,

Martin

Comment: Include the script that you are using and perhaps someone can help you spot the flaw in your logic?

Comment: I've duplicated your problem and tried several different methods of inserting an image in a form with the same result.  I think you should report to [Google Issue Tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker)

Comment: One possible way is through the Form API.  You can batchUpdate to create an image in the form but it requires an image URI, which I don't know how to create from the image.

Comment: Tanks for your time, I think I might report it to Google and let them resolve it. The code works well if there is 1 inline image and only 1 positioned image per paragraph. I might give it one last throw with the API idea and hopefully that may work. Thanks again.

Comment: There is another if statement that deals with inline images before the if statement that deals with positioned images; I didn't include it so as not to confuse matters as it would still work without.

Comment: What I did was create 3 positioned unique images in a Doc file and tried to transfer to a form and get 3 of the last image.  So I don't think you are doing anything wrong.

Comment: It might be that apps script isn't capable of doing it yet when transferring multiple positioned images anchored to a certain paragraph to a Google form.